# remove script in wordpress posts

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

My site in wordpress was hacked, the hacker injected a script inside the html code of the posts, so my wp_posts table in my DB need to be repaired, but I can`t figure out how to do it

I made a lot of research and tryes but without success, can someone help me please?

I`ll let a image of the malicious script, can someone tell me what is the query that I need to use in my phpMyAdmin?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you backup the wp_posts table and open the backup copy in a text editor like VisualStudio Code or Sublime text. There you can delete those malicious data from the table and reinstall back the wp_posts table with the clean data.

I hope this helps!